# How to return boolean to javascript function from swift using wkwebview

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

This is my function in android :

```
@JavascriptInterface
public boolean GetMobileVersion() {

    return true;
}
```

This is Calling function in JavaScript :

```
$(window).load(function () {

    IsCallByMobileApp = false;
    try {
          IsCallByMobileApp = app.GetMobileVersion();/*Is call by android app*/

    } catch (e) {
        IsCallByMobileApp = false;
    }

}
```

In iOS I am try to achieve same approach using `WKWebView` like this but it's not working:

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, 
    didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

    if(message.name == callbackhandler) {

        webView.evaluateJavaScript("GetMobileVersion();")  { (true, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print("there was an error")
                return
            }

            print(Bool(true))
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me How to send `true` to Javascript function? Please give me answer in detail because I am new to iOS and Swift.

Comment: Don't name a variable "true"...

Answer (score 2):

[image]
I have created a GitHub project for this. https://github.com/BKRApps/WKWebView-JS. check it out for more details.

**Update the JavaScript:**

```
 function getMobileVersion(){
        webkit.messageHandlers.VersionHandler.postMessage({})
    }

function receivedMobileVersion(mobileVersion){
        //here you will be getting the mobile version. Then execute the logic. 
        // i have added this only to cross check the version. you don't need to add this.

      if(mobileVersion === true) { 
      webkit.messageHandlers.VerifyHandler.postMessage({version:mobileVersion})
    }
 }

getMobileVersion()
```

**Add the below code to WKWebView Configuration:**

```
 configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "VersionHandler")
// i have added this only to cross check the version. you don't need to add this.
 configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "VerifyHandler")
```

**Update the WKScriptMessageHandler delegate:**

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    switch message.name {
    case "VersionHandler":
        let mobileVersion = true //write the version logic and send the true or false.
        let sendMobileVersionScript = "receivedMobileVersion(\(mobileVersion))"
        self.wkWebView?.evaluateJavaScript("\(sendMobileVersionScript)", completionHandler: { (any, error) in
                            print("hello")
        })
    case "VerifyHandler":
        print(message.body) // i have added this only to cross check the version. you 
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

for more info : http://igomobile.de/2017/03/06/wkwebview-return-a-value-from-native-code-to-javascript/

Comment: @jakir hussain,  I have provided the sample code and project. Check it out.

Comment: read my question GetMobileVersion() is call from javascript and if calling is success it will set IsCallByMobileApp  as true

Comment: in iOS, you can not call directly a native method from JS, like it exists in android. Please see the sample app which I created, it will fulfill your needs. Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: hey, i have updated the code and answer. check it out. https://github.com/BKRApps/WKWebView-JS

Comment: before i tried same thing but in onload function it's not working

Comment: in onLoad function just invoke, getMobileVersion(). That's it. You will get a callback in receivedMobileVersion(mobileversion) { }. In iOS, WkWebView and App run in two different processes. It is asynchronous.

Comment: If that is case update the answer and close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if with WKWebView is the same as webview but you could try with plaintext as following:

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, 
didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

if(message.name == callbackhandler) {

    webView.evaluateJavaScript("GetMobileVersion(true);")  { (true, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("there was an error")
            return
        }

        print(Bool(true))
    }
}
```

}